# XML XSD: Extendending complex type from imported XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to extend a complex type which is defined in an imported XSD. I set up the following example:

***Base.xsd:***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/base">
    <xs:complexType name="BaseType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="baseElement" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

***Extended.xsd:***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:base="http://www.example.com/base"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/extended"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/extended">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.com/base" schemaLocation="Base.xsd" />   
    <xs:complexType name="ExtendedType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="base:BaseType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="extendedElement" type="xs:int" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="ExtendedElement" type="ExtendedType" />
</xs:schema>
```

***Example.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extended:ExtendedElement xmlns:extended="http://www.example.com/extended"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/base"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/extended extended.xsd
                                         http://www.example.com/base base.xsd">
                                         
    <baseElement>someString</baseElement>
    <extendedElement>3</extendedElement>
</extended:ExtendedElement>
```

Now the problem with this XML is: I get a validation error that one of the elements "baseElement" is expected (even though the error is shown at exactly this element). Is there anything wrong with the XSD definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation error specifies that it doesn't expect a namespace qualified element in the XML :

> Invalid content was found starting with element `'{"http://www.example.com/base":baseElement}'`. One of `'{baseElement}'` is expected.

Since you defined the unqualified namespace `xmlns="http://www.example.com/base"` to point to `http://www.example.com/base`, every unqualified XML tags will be bound to this.

By changing this to `xmlns:base="http://www.example.com/base"` named-namespace, it should work

Comment: Thank you, this answers the question. Now: is there any way to adjust the XSD to make the XML valid? Unfortunately, the xml is fixed in my case.

Comment: Are the types indicated in the XSD the right ones ?

Comment: This was only an example. The types are not string and int, but are both complex types.

Comment: You need to make sure that `extendedElement` is in the right namespace, which in XSD 1.0 means it needs to be in a schema document with the base namespace as its target namespace, which means it should include the base schema document rather than importing it.

Comment: If I translate it well, change the `xs:import` directive in `extended.xsd` to this `<xs:include namespace="http://www.example.com/base" schemaLocation="base.xsd" />`. With that change, the XML doesn't yell a validation error for the `baseElement` tag

Comment: @MichaelKay including does not work here because the XSD is in a different namespace.

Comment: @user3726374 : did you try to change according my suggestion ?